# Fitting the iPhone 5 simulator on my screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Apple seems only to have included a retina version of the iPhone 5 (4-inch) simulator. This is great, but way too big to fit on my screen. Almost 35% is cut off, and I have a 23-inch monitor.

Are there any workarounds/hacks to make it fully display on my screen? Is it likely that Apple might include a non-retina (just normal sized) iPhone 5 simulator?

They have it for the iPhone 4, so not sure why they wouldn't include the same thing for iPhone 5..

Comment: They didn't include one for the iPhone 4 per say, the non-retina 3.5" device is designed to allow you to simulate a 3GS, which up until this week, was still available for purchase. It's unlikely they'll include a non-retina 4" simulator simply because that device will never exist.

Comment: where did you find the simulator I cant find it?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you look in Scale in the Window menu, you can make the simulator window 50% or 75% size.

Comment: cmd+1, cmd+2, cmd+3 for faster switching :)

Answer (score 13):

Just hit command-1, 2 or 3 to scale.

Comment: Scale is no longer available in XCode 9.2. Cmd+1 etc.. only seems to simulate screen touches....